# jquery - select all dropboxes in this form section

Tags: jquery

I was wondering this form which dynamic creates and clones div section which has  drop boxes.

I am looking for a code which will select all the dropboxes. Please note I would want  elements would id starting with ADVANCE*

I am not sure how to do this

Gordon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("select[id^=ADVANCE]")` resolve your problem.